# Import Browserify package into Ember-Cli project

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, browserify

I've installed the following library via bower: https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile/blob/master/isMobile.js

And imported it into my ember-cli project via in `ember-cli-build.js`:
`app.import('bower_components/isMobile/isMobile.min.js');`

While it's available via `window`, I also want to use it directly in Fastboot mode in node.

You can see in the source of the library, that it actually exports itself for Browserify via `module.exports = instantiate();`, so I tried to import it via
`import isMobile from '../bower_components/isMobile/isMobile.min.js';`, but that throws

`Error: Could not find module "frontend/bower_components/isMobile/isMobile.min.js" imported from "frontend/helpers/is-mobile-test"`

I think I'm just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned library seems to be available as a [node module](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile#nodejs-usage) as well. You can declare it as a fastboot dependency and execute it as mentioned in their docs when the app runs in fastboot mode